# Enabling SSL certificates on a service in GCP

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

I have nginx service created on a GKE cluster as a load balancer type.
I'm looking for enabling SSL certificates on this service. Is there any way in which I can achieve this in GKE?
Below is the nginx service YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "gitlab-docker-registry"
      port: 8123
      targetPort: 8123
    - name: "443"
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: You can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/custom-nginx) in order to find how to enable TLS/SSL when you are using nginx with GKE.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress), just take into consideration the [ports](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#open_ports) you can use and define the cert in the yaml file.

If you must use a "LoadBalancer" service type, then you must handle this on your nginx backend, modifying the nginx config file while sharing the certificate via [persistent volume](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes).

Comment: Using an ingress would change the functionality of our application itself. Is there any other functionality available in GKE to implement a layer 7 HTTP(S) load balancer so that the SSL certificate can be applied on that? There is a resource available in Azure called 'application gateway' which gives a similar functionality. Is there something similar in GKE/GCP as well?